# Making an Animation in Python with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to make a game but I can't get the animation to work. When I launch the game it loads all of the images on top of itself and it doesn't animate.
Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600

ship_width = 56
ship_height = 64

disp = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

pygame.display.set_caption("space_game")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("Backgrounds", "Space.png"))

img_names = ["sprite_00.png", "sprite_01.png", "sprite_02.png",   "sprite_03.png", "sprite_04.png", "sprite_05.png", "sprite_06.png", "sprite_07.png", "sprite_08.png", "sprite_09.png"] #i load all the images here

all_imgs = {}
for img in img_names:
    all_imgs[img] = pygame.image.load(img)

def gameLoop():
    x = (width * 0.45)
    y = (height * 0.8)

    x_ch = 0
    y_ch = 0

    x_bg = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord("a"):
                    x_ch = -5

                elif event.key == ord("d"):
                    x_ch = 5

                elif event.key == ord("w"):
                    y_ch = -5

                elif event.key == ord("s"):
                    y_ch = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord("a") or event.key == ord("d"):
                    x_ch = 0

                if event.key == ord("w") or event.key == ord("s"):
                    y_ch = 0

        x += x_ch
        y += y_ch

        if x > width - ship_width or x < 0:
            x_ch = 0

        if y > height - ship_height or y < 0:
            y_ch = 0

        x_loop = x_bg % background.get_rect().height
        disp.blit(background, (0, x_loop - background.get_rect().height))

        if x_loop < height:
            disp.blit(background, (0, x_loop))

        x_bg += 5

        for img in img_names:
            disp.blit(all_imgs[img], (x, y)) #but this part doesnt work it blits 

                                             #all the images on top of eachother
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

For some reason it doesnt animate it just loads all the images on top of eachother please help me. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your `for img in img_names:` loop just blits all images. My recommendation would be to store the images/pygame.Surfaces in a list and then use an `index` variable that keeps track of the current image.

So roughly:

```
images = [image1, image2, etc.]
index = 0

while True:
    index += 1
    # Modulo to keep the index in the correct range.
    index %= len(images)
    current_image = images[index]
    disp.blit(current_image, position)
```

Note that this example is frame rate bound and I'd recommend to increment the `index` after some time interval instead.

**Addendum:** To slow the animation down, you can for example count the frames and increment the index only if the `frame_count` is greater than 3.

```
images = [image1, image2, etc.]
index = 0
frame_count = 0

while True:
    frame_count += 1
    if frame_count > 3:
        frame_count = 0
        index += 1
        index %= len(images)
        current_image = images[index]

    disp.blit(current_image, position)
```

But that would still be frame rate bound.

**The right way** to do it, is to use a `timer` variable and to add the time that `clock.tick` returns to it, and if the timer is above some arbitrary threshold, increment the index and change the image.

```
images = [image1, image2, etc.]
index = 0
current_image = images[index]
timer = 0
dt = 0

while True:
    timer += dt
    # If 1 second has passed.
    if timer > 1:
        timer = 0
        index += 1
        index %= len(images)
        current_image = images[index]

    screen.blit(current_image, position)

    # dt is the time that has passed since the last clock.tick call.
    # Divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds.
    dt = clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
```

Comment: I can show you a frame rate independent version as well if you want.

Comment: when i lauch i get this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'index' referenced before assignment

Comment: That means you haven't defined the variable `index` in your function.

Comment: i still get this error: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str do you want me to update my code?

Comment: The images in the list have to be `pygame.Surface`s not strings, so the loaded images.

Comment: so i should load the images first?

Comment: Yep, just append them to a list instead of the `all_imgs` dictionary.

Comment: when i launch it now it just opens a black screen without any errors

Comment: Great! You probably need a way to slow the animation down now, otherwise the program updates the image each frame.